# Vue js dynamic component nesting

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am able to add component from array variables to main component using following way:

```
<component :is="currentTabComponent"></component>
```

Now I want to add another dynamic component inside rendered component.

If u say **using slot**  then how can i access specific component's slot and push my **variable component** to that slot.

https://jsfiddle.net/capt8ndq/42/

I have created example fiddle have mainContainer->slider->sliderContent(this may have further nesting) structure.

I am getting following error after some progress

```
Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Anonymous>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Difficult to answer from the limited details, but you would render a component in the dynamic component's slot the same way you would with any other component; [by putting it between the tags](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/oyWJMd?editors=1010).

Comment: @Bert u are going in the right direction. the child component u added in slot tag should be added there dynamic bcos child component may have another component to render inside child component. if its 5 level nesting then how can i do that using script.....

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer the question without specifics.

Comment: @Bert I have added example fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using slot, make use of props by passing props down to that rendered component and also modify that rendered component to also has `<component :is="componentFromProps"></component>`.